# Placing .bat and .vbs script in system start-up in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, programming-languages

I have created a basic .bat and a .vbs script in Windows 10. Now I want the script to automatically place itself in startup folder whenever it is opened for the first time. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: What is this code? What does this code means?

Comment: You're not really supposed to put files in that directory, it is intended for shortcuts to files. I would suggest therefore that your scripts create shortcuts to themselves in that directory instead. There are however other ways to run scripts on startup, log on, log off, shutdown etc. which you may want to investigate further, before taking this route.

Comment: You have other idea on how to get this script into destined folder? @Compo

Comment: For me, the task is trivial, I would do as I've already explained. My [tag:batch-file] and my [tag:vbscript] would each create a shortcut to themselves from within their own code. There are several examples on this site for creating shortcuts under both tags, and I'm sure that there are examples for locating the `Startup` directory. Please note however, that I'm sure that there are new limitations with what is allowed to run from that location without disabling UAC.